# nuget install does not get dependencies inside dependent packages

Tags: .net, nuget, dependency-management, nuget-cli

I'm using NuGet CLI tool to manage package dependencies in a non-VisualStudio environment.
Is there a way to use the packages.config file with the command install and get all dependencies that the listed dependencies in the packages.config file have? The whole dependency graph.

Example:
My packages.config lists one dependency A.
The A package has a dependency B.

If I run nuget install packages.config I only get package A.

If I run nuget install A I also get B.

I'm afraid I have to write a script to read the packages.config, looping through all dependencies calling install for each, to make this work.

Are there any other possibilities just using the CLI tool?

Comment: Have you tried [`nuget restore <projectPath> [options]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-restore#usage)? Since you already have the packages.config file, it seems like a restore would work for you.

Comment: @techvice Because of the fact that my packages.config file only contains direct dependencies, the restore command works exactly as `nuget install packages.config`, thus not download/unpack the dependency B.

Comment: Using the latest NuGet (v4.4.1), when I run the command `nuget install xunit`, it will not only install xunit but all of the dependencies. Are you using the latest version of [NuGet](https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe)?

Comment: @techvice Yes I am, and I know that install with one package works, but want one command that gets one file as input with only the direct dependencies that gets all sub-dependencies.

Comment: @JanLovstrand, did you ever figure this out? I had the exact same expectation. I'm at version 4.9.4 and it still has this behavior, so I'm guessing it's how they intend it to operate.

Comment: @Craig I had to do as I stated. Read the read out the dependencies and call install for each one of them.